# Extending PhotonServer for new project

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, extending, photon

I am working with PhotonServer for a Unity3d project. I started off with a simple extension of the ApplicationBase class to get it up and running. Now I would like to save myself some heavy lifting and extend the LiteLobby or even LoadBalanced projects. Putting my own code on top of that Exitgames has already made.

I am using Photon 3.4 and Visual Studio 2013.

I am creating a new project. Adding an existing project: Lite and LiteLobby. Add references to each inside of the MyServer project.

This is where I am doing something wrong:

LiteLobbyApplication extends LiteApplication
LiteApplication extends ApplicationBase

When I try to extend my MyServerApplication with anything but ApplicationBase I am unable to implement the interface. The provided code shows that is alerady done so it seems like conceptually I am doing something wrong.

If the LiteLobbyApplication extends the LiteApplication successfully. Why can I extend neither?

My goal is to set this up in a way that when new releases of Photon come out I wont have to mess around with moving files and references.

TLDR: How do I properly extend LiteLobby/LoadBalancing projects when starting a new project?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that even though the auto implement features dont seem to handle the nested interface requirements all that well. If you just manually override them it works perfectly fine. I was over complicating it and assuming there was a mysterious missing piece!

```
public class MyServerMasterApplication : MasterApplication
{
    protected override PeerBase CreatePeer(InitRequest initRequest)
    {
        return base.CreatePeer(initRequest);
    }

    protected override void Initialize()
    {
        base.Initialize();
    }

    protected override void Setup()
    {
        base.Setup();
    }

    protected override void TearDown()
    {
        base.TearDown();
    }
}
```